# Sitecore User Group Sep 2018 Meetup - Queen City, Manchester, NH

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

We are extremely pumped to announce the Sep meetup of the Queen City Sitecore User Group.

Three excellent presentation are lined up for this SUG:

1. Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0.2 - Rob Earlam, Technical Evangelist at Sitecore
2. Sitecore Experience Accelerator(SXA): Accelerate your experience - Amitabh Vyas, Sitecore Architect
3. Sitecore Experience Forms - Mike Reynolds, Sitecore MVP and Sitecore Architect

Date & Time (EST):- Wednesday, Sep, 12, 2018 6:00 PM

Date & Time (UTC):- Wednesday, Sep, 12, 2018 10:00 PM

Venue:- SilverTech Inc, 196 Bridge Street, Manchester, NH 03104

[Click here for more details and RSVP](https://www.meetup.com/Queen-City-Sitecore-User-Group/events/254209319/).